# How to use Tor via VPN or ssh?

Tags: configuration, vpn, ssh

Tor is blocked at my university network but I can use a free VPN and ssh  named *Psiphon3* and I use it for accessing internet but, I am unable to open Tor via the VPN. My question is how to use the VPN to connect to Tor network?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Tor.SE. This question looks like it would be better if split into several questions. I've removed the bit about Torrents (as this is a duplicate of other questions on this site), and it's unlear if you want ot use VPN or SSH from your question. Either way, this is a probably also a duplicate. Could you please rephrase your question to be more clear, or do a search and see if your question is already asnwered elsewhere on this site (there are several questions about using Tor over VPN's or with SSH)? Thanks!

Comment: How to use vpn for tor(use tor through vpn) as i can't directly operate tor because it is blocked?

Comment: Forget about torrent thing i will search it.thanks

Comment: @hellodear, Start the VPN. Once you started the VPN and it start running, Start the Tor Browser. Report if you have any problem.